# sbt, libraryDependencies without groupID and revision?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

From sbt [documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Dependencies), the libraryDependencies format is:

```
libraryDependencies += groupID % artifactID % revision
```

For example:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.4"
```

However, in the [Play 2.6.x Scala Starter Example](https://www.playframework.com/download#starters) project, the **guice** libraryDependencies in build.sbt shows only

```
libraryDependencies += guice
```

How do we know which **guice** version will be adopted by sbt or the format is for some specific purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Play Framework, you normally setup your project using the [special sbt plugin](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/BuildOverview#Play-plugin-for-sbt-(/project/plugins.sbt)). You should have it in your `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "...")
```

This plugin defines values for different optional dependencies such as `guice` in your question. So you can go to the sbt plugin source and check what is this `guice` exactly ([here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/683e8c01b5c231adec91d9d0da72658fdd516836/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlayImport.scala#L73)):

```
val guice = component("play-guice")
```

And `component` is defined as

```
def component(id: String) = "com.typesafe.play" %% id % play.core.PlayVersion.current
```

So it actually refers to the `play-guice` subproject of the Play framework and it [depends](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/683e8c01b5c231adec91d9d0da72658fdd516836/framework/build.sbt#L175) on `guiceDeps`, which are defined in the [`playframework/framework/project/Dependencies.scala`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/683e8c01b5c231adec91d9d0da72658fdd516836/framework/project/Dependencies.scala#L132-L136):

```
val guiceVersion = "4.2.0"
val guiceDeps = Seq(
  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % guiceVersion,
  "com.google.inject.extensions" % "guice-assistedinject" % guiceVersion
)
```

---

This is just to show where does it come from. Normally, when you want to check your transitive dependencies, you should use [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plugin. It can list all your dependencies (with their versions and other useful information) in the sbt shell or visualize it as a tree or a graph.